# Javascript regexp multiple matches seperated by a character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the awesomplete autosuggest plugin to show suggestions to an input.
I want to match only from beginning of words, and match several places seperated by a space.

Example:
input = "I don't know how to use RegExp correctly".

If I type "kno reg", or "corr ho" - there should be a match.
but not if I type "kno ow", or "se corr".

So far I have this to match only beginning of words:

```
_.FILTER_WORDSTART = function(text, input) {
    return RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + $.regExpEscape(input.trim()), "i").test(text);
};

$.regExpEscape = function (s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\&");
};
```

This works, but I also need it to match several places separated by a space.

(EDIT)
Above part is solved.

Now I have:

```
_.FILTER_WORDSTART = function(text, input) {
    return input.split(/\s+/).every(function(word) { return RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + $.regExpEscape(word.trim()), "i").exec(text); });
};

$.regExpEscape = function (s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\&");
};

// Highlight function
_.ITEM = function (text, input) {
    var html = input === '' ? text : text.replace(RegExp($.regExpEscape(input.trim()), "gi"), "<mark>$&</mark>");
    return $.create("li", {
        innerHTML: html,
        "aria-selected": "false"
    });
};
```

How do I get the highlight function to also highlight every word seperated by a space?
The _.FILTER_WORDSTART will always return true or false, even if i set the "exec" on the regex instead of "test".
But I need the actual match in the highlight function. Any help on how I would put this?

Comment: You will need to `split` the input on spaces, and consider each as a separate regex, and then return true if all of the regexes match.

Comment: That makes sense. Could you show my an example of how you would write that?

Comment: `input.split(/\s+/).every(function(word) { return _.FILTER_WORDSTART(text, word) })`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! :D

Comment: @4castle: Ping.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @4castle - I ran into a new problem, would you mind checking the edit of my post?